# Jenkins job's console log has messy code, chinese language show unnormaly

Tags: python, node.js, jenkins

I'm try to set LANG to zh.CH.UTF-8 and set tomcat server.xml URIEncoding=UTF-8 restart jenkins, it also has messy code in chinese language.
[image: pic1]

I use 'Execute Windows batch command' to run a personal **python** script
for example: 
cd xxx/xx/
py testPyScript.py
Some Chinese language in testPyScript.py, it's normally in the Jenkins console.

But when I use 'Execute Windows batch command' to run a personal **nodejs** script
for example:
cd xxx/xxx
node testNodeScript.js
Some Chinese languages in testNodeScript.js, it's unnormally in the jenkins console.

some detail to see flow pictures
[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]

Comment: Probably your Windows nodes are configured to use some legacy code page instead of UTF-8. See if you can make them output UTF-8 instead, but this is highly speculative because your question doesn't really reveal anything about how the web server etc is configured. Does it display a character set in the HTTP headers or in the meta tags?

Comment: How can i find "nodes are configured to use some legacy code page instead of UTF-8" in my Windows

Comment: In very brief, `chcp` should display which code page is currently active, and with an argument allow you to change the system encoding. How `node` reacts to that is completely beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Or maybe it's because you have a typo in your `LANG` variable, it should be `zh_CN.UTF-8` with an underscore between the language and the region.